# Longest sequence of same numbers in array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to execute this so that it prints out the longest sequence of the same number. I've just edited it but it's telling me to place a return statement . Here's my code:

```
public class A1Q3 {
    private static int getLongestRun(int[] array){ 
        int count = 1; 
        int max = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
                 count++;
            } else {
                 count = 1;
            }
              if (count > max){
                  max = count;
        }   
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         int[] array = new int[]{5, 6, 6, 45, -2, -9, 56};
         System.out.println(getLongestRun(array));
     }    
}
```

Comment: " I'm not too confident with it" - you don't have to be: simply run it on a few examples and see if it works (hint: it doesn't).

Comment: Your count will get reset to one when a number not being the one before.  You need to save the longest count at any point into another variable `currentMax` and after `count++` `if(count>currentMax) currentMax=count;` At the end you will have the maximum in `currentMax``

Comment: There is a code review stack exchange Community where you can post this  question.

Comment: @VHS no he can't, you can only review *working* code there. Above code doesn't even compile. Please read the help center of SO sites before posting there (or advising it to others)

Comment: Updated my answer below to include how to get the code working in addition to fixing the logical errors.

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing a closing parenthesis for the getLongestRun() function and a return statement. You want to return the max variable.**

Also, instead of

```
System.out.println(count);
```

Try:

```
System.out.println(getLongestRun(array));
```

to actually use the function you made. Your function is still not correct, however. You are returning the current streak count, not the longest streak count. You correctly reset the count back to 1 after the streak ends, but you need another variable named something like max to store the total maximum in addition to the current streak.

Comment: Actually, the code is not returning anything, which is also why it doesn't compile.

Comment: It's also missing a closing parenthesis for the getLongestRun() function. I'll add that.